How can I increase optimisation of a GIF of an old film?
A skiatron is a kind of black-on-white display system from the 1940s. I made a gif of one for Wikipedia, which I clipped from a film called "RDF to Radar".
My problem is that the gif is huge: over 3MB for 43 frames. The usual optimisation methods I know are defeated by the fact that the contrast on the film flickers, so the delta between the frames is noisy.

Is there some kind of filter I can run over the clip before I create the gif?

In Adobe Photoshop, the Save for Web tool, with the Selective algorithm and the Diffusion option allows you to do lossy compression on the GIF frames which seems to give a smaller size GIF file, with a slight reduction in image quality. (For example, with 25% compression, the file size was reduced to around 1.2 MB with an "acceptable" level of noise / graininess in the image).
Please see this guide - How To Export A GIF From Photoshop - to learn and experiment with the many available options.
If you do not have Adobe Photoshop, use this free online GIF optimizer and compressor which offers some similar, but limited, options for optimizing and compressing a GIF file. One feature in particular that I liked is dropping every nth frame of the GIF animation to create a smaller GIF file size. Photoshop doesn't have this option (i.e. you have to do it manually in it).
Also consider the new JPEG XL format that now supports animation, with progressive loading. Testing with the free online GIF to JXL converter, I was able to get a JXL file of your animation that was only 1.12 MB (a 65% reduction) without any perceptible loss in image quality.
